# How to reference an AMP HTML page in a normal HTML page

Tags: amp-html

How do I link to an AMP HTML page in a normal HTML page.

The example on GitHub specifies a canonical page which I guess refers to the "normal" HTML page. https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml#how-does-amp-html-work

```
<link rel="canonical" href="hello-world.html" >
```

But how does the "normal" page link to the AMP HTML page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to [niemanlab.org](http://www.niemanlab.org/2015/10/get-ampd-heres-what-publishers-need-to-know-about-googles-new-plan-to-speed-up-your-website/) it’s done like this:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="hello-its-an-amp-page.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I only write in AMP, the way to do it would be like this if my page name was index.html:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="index.html">
```

That way, it always refers to itself instead of a regular HTML page. If there are any doubts, use Google Chrome to test/validate the page by putting #development=1 at the end of the URL.